# Multiple text filters in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to filter through my data with two text boxes, StaffTotalSearchText1 and StaffTotalSearchText2.

I understand that only the most recent DoCmd.ApplyFilter command appies, and that means I don't know how to apply two text filters.

Edit: Solution found - see Johnny's RecordSource code
One way of applying a filter is to do it do the loaded data (RecordSource) - still allowing a "DoCmd.ApplyFilter" to be used.

I've created  a "lock filter 1" button. When enabled, the filter applies; when disabled, there is no filter.

Johhny's answer has the correct code to filter the loaded data upon loading it.

Comment: It would be much easier if you just refreshed the DataSource and used the filter on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM StaffTable " & _
"WHERE [Forename] Like '*" & [Forms]![StaffTotalQuery]![StaffTotalSearchText1] & "*' " & _
   "Or [Surname] Like '*" & me![StaffTotalSearchText1] & "*' " & _
   "Or [ProfessionalID] Like '*" & me![StaffTotalSearchText1] & "*'"
```

Assuming you're pointing to the correct objects (I'm guessing Forename is on a different form?  It's the only one you're referencing by form name), this should work.

Comment: Did it run correctly?  Just so you know, the way it's written it's going to return results when *any* of those conditions are met, because you're using "Or".  If you want to return only results where *all* conditions are met, use "And".

Comment: Please double-check my edit, and then I'll clean up my comments under this answer.

Comment: P.P.S. Can we extend this method, or apply another method, to allow the use of three text filters?

Comment: You can add as many filters as you want.  You can make some of them conditional.  You can pretty much do anything.  As far as "friending", I don't think this site has an option for that.

Answer (score 3):

Just use both values in filter and the same code in both filter events:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", _
 "[Forename] Like '*" & me![StaffTotalSearchText1] & "*'" & _
 " Or [Surname] Like '*" & me![StaffTotalSearchText1] & "*'" & _
 " Or [Forename] Like '*" & me[StaffTotalSearchText2] & "*'" & _
 " Or [Surname] Like '*" & me[StaffTotalSearchText2] & "*'"
```

**Edit**: applying the second filter after the first:

```
If Not IsNull(Me![StaffTotalSearchText1]) And Len(Me![StaffTotalSearchText1] & "") <> "" Then
    strFilter = "[Forename] Like '*" & Me![StaffTotalSearchText1] & "*'" & _
              " Or [Surname] Like '*" & Me![StaffTotalSearchText1] & "*'"
    If Not IsNull(Me![StaffTotalSearchText2]) And Len(Me![StaffTotalSearchText2] & "") <> "" Then
        strFilter = "(" & strFilter & ") AND " & _
                  "( [Forename] Like '*" & Me![StaffTotalSearchText2] & "*'" & _
                  " Or [Surname] Like '*" & Me![StaffTotalSearchText2] & "*')"
    End If
End If

DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", strFilter
```

If you want to use `RecordSource` you can use the same filter but must add the SQL for select command:

```
strFilter = ""

If Not IsNull(Me![StaffTotalSearchText1]) And Len(Me![StaffTotalSearchText1] & "") <> "" Then
    strFilter = "[Forename] Like '*" & Me![StaffTotalSearchText1] & "*'" & _
              " Or [Surname] Like '*" & Me![StaffTotalSearchText1] & "*'"
    If Not IsNull(Me![StaffTotalSearchText2]) And Len(Me![StaffTotalSearchText2] & "") <> "" Then
        strFilter = "(" & strFilter & ") AND " & _
                  "( [Forename] Like '*" & Me![StaffTotalSearchText2] & "*'" & _
                  " Or [Surname] Like '*" & Me![StaffTotalSearchText2] & "*')"
    End If
End If

If strFilter <> "" Then
    strFilter = "SELECT * FROM StaffTable WHERE " & strFilter
Else
    strFilter = "[StaffTable]"
End If

Me.RecordSource = strFilter
```

Comment: With this code, only the text in StaffTotalSearchText1 acts as a filter. The other text entry item is definitely named"StaffTotalSearchText2"

Comment: @Idios changed my answer with fix

Comment: Great!...  Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you, that will help to my account :-)

Comment: Okay, I think I need to be more specific: I don't want to allow results which match either text field, I want to first filter my data with StaffTotalSearchText1, and then to filter this filtered data with StaffTotalSearchText2

Comment: @Idios I added more code to permit both search criteria